# Javascript Search Function

Tags: javascript, search

I am trying to write a search function to search through a longer string to see if it contains a smaller string. I pass both strings to the function as parameters. This is my code:

```
 var search = function(wordToFind, stringToSearch) {
    for (var a = 0; a<stringToSearch.length; a++) {
     if(wordToFind.substring(0,wordToFind.length).toLowerCase()===stringToSearch.substring(a,a+wordToFind.length).toLowerCase()) {
            return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
       }
  }
```

When I pass it "hello", it returns true, but when I pass it any other combination of words, it returns false. Can someone please help/explain why?

Comment: did you know that strings have an `indexOf` method that you can use?

Comment: oh, and `wordToFind.substring(0,wordToFind.length)` can be written as simply `wordToFind`

Comment: What is the indexOf method? Sorry I am pretty new to coding!

Comment: and you return false unless the word is at the beginning of the string to search - so, that will always fail (except in the aforementioned circumstance) ... don't have an else, and have the return false outside of the for loop

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: Thank you so much! This totally solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the ES6 `includes` method. It returns true if a string was found within another string.

```js
const string = 'sarasa';
const subString = 'rasa';
const anotherString = 'foo';

console.log(string.includes(subString));
console.log(string.includes(anotherString));
```